# What does the "Bonus Chest" option in the New World options do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In the new version of Minecraft there's a "Bonus Chest" toggle in the New World options.

[image: Screenshot of Bonus Chest option]

So, what's up with that? Where does the chest appear, and what will I find in it?

Comment: Don't forget, if the answer is acceptable to you, click the checkmark by the answer!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Basically, it's a "starter kit", per se, for players in Minecraft.

From [the Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bonus_chest#Bonus_chest):

> A bonus chest will generate near the player's spawn if the Bonus Chest
> option is enabled in the World Options menu. These chests only
> generate once per world. This is suggested for new players who are
> unfamiliar with the game's mechanics.
> Bonus chests contain:
>
> - Wooden or stone pickaxes
> - Wooden or stone axes
> - Logs
> - Wooden planks
> - Sticks
> - Bread
> - Apples
>
> Four torches will spawn around the chest.

Comment: Additionally, you can destroy the chest and take it with you. Worth pointing out for anyone new to the game.

Comment: If you're on a server, does this spawn a bonus chest per player?

Comment: @Scoooooby No Only once the world is created.